# How to know the type of data in clipboard through python?

Tags: python, winapi

By use Python, and win32api, how to know the current data type in clipboard?

I know I can use the statement like:

```
GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT)
```

but what if I don't know the type of data?

Comment: because I'd like to get the data in clipboard and no matter what the data is.

Comment: Why not do some research. If you read the documentation for the function you are calling you'd have found the entire clipboard api.

Comment: @David Heffernan thanks a lot and I have already how to do it.

Comment: If you already read that documentation, why would you be asking this question at all? You already know the answer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  to info others.

Comment: I don't really see any information for others. I see a poorly researched question, part of which ("what about folder") is very unclear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you will see the information soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `EnumClipboardFormats` to know what type you can get.

```
import win32clipboard as clipboard
def getTheClipboardType():
    formats = []
    clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    lastFormat = 0
    while True:
        nextFormat = clipboard.EnumClipboardFormats(lastFormat)
        if 0 == nextFormat:
             # all done -- get out of the loop
             break
        else:
             formats.append(nextFormat)
             lastFormat = nextFormat
    clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    return formats
```

By launch the function, you will get a list, and it contains the type number of data. Such as:

```
[13, 1, 49427, 49953, 49422, 49304, 16, 7]
```

Comment: It sounds like you really want [IsClipboardFormatAvailable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649047.aspx), since you are looking for a **specific** clipboard format.